# Jquery accordion bug with multiple nested accordions

Tags: jquery, nested, accordion

http://jsbin.com/uxafu3/14/edit

Here is a link showing what seems to be a bug in the Jquery accordion.
The first nested accordion (1, 1a, 1b) works just fine and expands as it should.

hoever with second nested accordtion (2, 2a, 2b) the arrow changes to show that it's expanding but no content comes out.

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set the `autoHeight` option to `false` (default is `true`), worked for me.
Besides, I suppose you wouldn't need an accordion like that to expand its say 18349pxs all the way down on your website, use `overflow: scroll;` to control the content instead.

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/5yyUE/) working correctly by changing the css to [base theme](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)

the bug report had indicated that it had been fixed so so I to away all css then went and got the current css and there we go!

Comment: Am I missing something. In chrome dev on jsfiddle it does not work for me with the link you posted.

1a and 2a still works however 2a and 2b still does not work. I have selected latest jquery (1.5.1) in the dropdown on the left.

Comment: @Rickard Liljeberg so when you click the link I posted it defaults to havinng 1 open which shows 1a and 1b right ? then when you click on 2 it should hide 1a and 1 b and show 2a and 2b, and it does not do that for you ?

Comment: Yes it does hide 1a and 1b, that bit works. It also does display 2a and 2b. So far everything works. The problem is that clicking on 2a and 2b did not show any content.

However with your last demo that you sent it does display the content from 2a and 2b when clicked (whats the difference??)
Only remaining problem is that it prints the content of 2a over the 2b link.

Comment: Nevermind I noticed they both worked the same. So problem seems to be on 2a it prints the content over the 2b-link

Comment: Also as you noted if I add the css it looks like on jsbin and 2a and 2b does not toggle at all (altho 2a displays half right to begin with)

Comment: Yes my answer is not a solution but more points out that it's a CSS problem or at least thats what it appears to be I'll play around with it today and see what I can find

Comment: Thank you!

There is one thing tho, when you click 2a and 2b (without css) you can see that they jump up and then display data.

whereas on 1a and 1b they slide up smoothly. So I don't think it's only a css problem.

Comment: And another strange behaviour. On my site I have overridden the navigationFilter so that I can get a deep nested accordion to open up on pageload by sending in domain.com/page/#myNestedID

And when I tried that now, all of a sudden different accordions worked, one that refused to open before now worked fine, and one that worked fine before no longer works.

Just strange

Comment: Okay so after some more test I have isolated that it is a problem with cousin containers. And which ones work will be decided from which one is opened on load.

Any cousin will not work. All sibblings work, and parents.
but cousins does not work.

which can be seen in our example. 2a and 2b is cousins of 1a and 1b.

and if you with navigationFilter would make sure 2a or 2b opened on load they would work and 1a and 1b would not.

Comment: Thank you for the find. However when I look at the bugreport and bugfix and then check the code in the plugin it is the new corrected code.

And the workaround does not work for me either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now it's sort of working in IE9 and FF4 but still not in chrome-dev. Chrome looks the same and IE and FF get scrollbars in the content of 2a and 2b (unlike 1a and 1b) so it seems they don't expand correctly.

Comment: @Rickard Liljeberg i would say at this point you ahave a css issue